# SQL Server view or procedure with bitand

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database with this data (sample row):

```
IP      | DATETIME            | TOTALTIME1 | OUTPUT | 
-----------------------------------------------------
x.x.x.x | 30.10.2014 11:23:39 |     123    |    3   |
```

I want to load the data into a c# dataset but there a too much entries so I looking for a solution to load only the data that I need and the processing takes the database itself.

What I need is a view or something I can use from c# with the selected and processed data:

`ID1` and `ID2` are new columns

```
IP | DATETIME | TOTALTIME1 | OUTPUT | ID1 | ID2 |
```

Now I have to check the bit of the row "OUTPUT", if the first bit = 1 then in the row "ID1" should be "true". Something like this:

```
BITAND(OUTPUT, 1) <> 0 THEN ID1 = "TRUE"
```

So how can I makes this? Is it possible to create a new view or do I need a procedure? 
I would like to load the data of the view/procedure in c# with SQL Server.

Thanks!

### Solution

```
CASE BITAND(RAWOUTPUT1, POWER(2,n-1)) WHEN 0 THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS ID1
```

Comment: It's a **procedure** - not a *prodcedure*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of bitwise operators in SQL Server. See the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176122.aspx

What you need is something like this:

```
SELECT CASE (OutputColumn & 1) WHEN 0 THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS ID1,
       CASE (OutputColumn & 2) WHEN 0 THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS ID2,
       * -- Other columns here, etc.
```

Comment: That's it `CASE BITAND(RAWOUTPUT1, POWER(2,n-1)) WHEN 0 THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS ID1,`